# How to export videos with transparent background from Keynote app?

Tags: export, transparency, video, keynote

I'm pretty new to Keynote app and I've created a series of animated presentations I'd like to export as video with a transparent background. I'm using its latest update version 6.5.3, so far the most recent one. Perhaps I'm missing something, but it turns out I simply can't find which settings to tweak in order to do that.

Bellow are the actual version's export as Quicktime video options, it seems there's no option to include transparency. By choosing the "Custom" option only allows to set a custom crop size for the video.

[image: Actual version video export options]

In older versions an option to include transparency was available.

[image: Older versions video export options]

My slideshow presentation was created using only one slide with the background color set to 0%, this seems not to help as it results on a video with plain black background after export.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue, but I've just found a solution! In Export options, select "Format > Custom", then choose at Compression Type: "Apple ProRes 4444".

Follow these steps and Keynote will create a transparent background MOV file.

Cheers!

Comment: I can't get this to work now.  Can you tell me what other settings you applied to achieve this - e.g., slide background fill settings, etc.?  Thanks.

Comment: Hi Jason, your slide background fill must be transparent. Just set the color opacity to 0% and follow the steps above.

Comment: Thanks Gustavo for following up.  Here's what I figured out:  The technique you describe will NOT work if you use the **Magic Move** transition between slides (in that case it creates a black background).  Otherwise it does seem to work.  This is a bummer since the Magic Move animation was the main reason I was using Keynote to generate the video (to be overlaid on another video).  If anyone finds a solution to this (when using Magic Move), I'd love to hear about it.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I have your solution. I was looking for the same problem as well. What you need to do is change your background to green.

[image]

This will then allow you to use the green screen feature in iMovie: Drag your clip in --> Picture in picture:

[image]

--> Green/Blue Screen:

[image]

I guess better late than never...

Comment: The green screen was brilliant. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know how to do this.

- Remove the background (no background option) for all the slides.
- Remove the background (no background option) for the master slides.
- Export using Apple ProRes 4444.

Works like a dream.

Answer (score 1):

I'm viewing this June 2019. I placed an MPEG-4 movie (6 seconds) needed for an intro into Keynote 9.0.2 and I also got a black screen at the end after rendering. Exporting using Apple ProRes 4444 made no difference.

My fix was simple: Trim off black from the clip in iMovie.

I needed to import to iMovie with the video it precedes anyway so no big deal for me. But anyone else can do the same to remove unwanted black end footage and then just export/ share it out of iMovie as needed.